# java: sortedList class Comparable error

Tags: java

I have these two classes, one of them is the `sortedLinkedList` class that has the `Comparable` with a generic type. When I implement them in the main:

```
SortedListInterface<Apartment> aptList=new SortedLinkedList<Apartment>();
```

it will show this error:

> Test.java:12: error: type argument Apartment is not within bounds of
>   type-variable T SortedListInterface aptList=new
>   SortedLinkedList();
>                       ^   where T is a type-variable:
>       T extends Comparable declared in interface SortedListInterface

`Apartment` class:

```
/**A class that holds Apartment informations*/
public class Apartment{

   private String id;
   private int yearsLeft;

//class methods

}//end Apartment class
```

`SortedLinkedList` class:

```
/**
 * A class that implements the ADT sorted list by using a chain of nodes.
 * Duplicate entries are allowed.
 *
 * @author Frank M. Carrano
 * @version 2.0
 */
public class SortedLinkedList<T extends Comparable<? super T>>
             implements SortedListInterface<T>
{
    //class methods
} // end SortedLinkedList
```

The idea is I want to sort all Apartments according to their years (`int yearsLeft`), but I'm new to the `Comparable` class, so I don't know how to work with it probably.

my question is: How to fix the error? with explanation if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be able to use the `Apartment` with `SortedLinkedList`,
it needs to implement the `Comparable` interface, for example:

```
  class Apartment implements Comparable<Apartment> {
    @Override
    public int compareTo(Apartment o) {
      return 0;
    }

    // ... the rest of your code
  }
```

How do you want to order apartments?
You need to implement the `compareTo` method accordingly.
If you want to order apartments by `yearsLeft`, you could write that as:

```
@Override
public int compareTo(Apartment o) {
  return Integer.compare(yearsLeft, o.yearsLeft);
}
```

To order by `yearsLeft` in reverse order, you could write that as:

```
@Override
public int compareTo(Apartment o) {
  return -Integer.compare(yearsLeft, o.yearsLeft);
}
```

You can read more about the `Comparable` interface in the [JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html).

Answer (score 0):

You define `SortedLinkedList` as `SortedLinkedList <T extends Comparable<? super T>>`

that means T (your appartement class) must be something that extends `Comparable<? super T>`

your appartement class doesn't extends Comparable

Answer (score 0):

Simply you have defined the class `SortedLinkedList` as generic class with a conditional type parameter `T extends Comparable<? super T>` .

So in instantiation, the type parameter you pass must satisfy.

But your class `Apartment` doesn't satisfy it.

Simply make class `Apartment` implements `Comparable<Apartment>`